# Passing a selected dropdown item to route

Tags: php, laravel

Can't figure how to pass the selected item->id to my route

I'm generating a dropdown from database.

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="">Tallas disponibles</label>
       <select class="form-control" name="" id="">
           @foreach ($subproducts as $subproduct)
              <option value="{{ $subproduct->id}}">{{$subproduct->description}}</option>
           @endforeach
        </select>
</div>
```

Using a `<form action="{{ route ('cart.add', $subproduct->id)}}"`doesn't work also adding a `<a href="{{ route ('cart.add', $subproduct->id)}}" >` after dropdown wont also do the job.

Route is

```
Route::get('/add-to-cart/{product}', 'CartController@add')->name('cart.add');
```

and controller

```
public function add (Product $product) {

    // dd ($product);

    \Cart::add(array(
        'id' => $product->id,
        'name' => $product->description,
        'price' => $product->price,
        'quantity' => 1,
        'attributes' => array(),
        'associatedModel' => $product
    ));

    return back();
}
```

It's probably something easy to figure, but I can't see what it is.

Thank you all,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form action="{{ url('cart.add') }}" method="get">
 <div class="form-group">
   <label for="">Tallas disponibles</label>
   <select class="form-control" name="product" id="">
     @foreach ($subproducts as $subproduct)
        <option value="{{ $subproduct->id}}">{{$subproduct->description}}</option>
     @endforeach
   </select>
 </div>
 <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

**Your route**

`Route::get('/add-to-cart', 'CartController@add')->name('cart.add');`

**Your controller**

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
..
public function add (Request $request) {

    dd($request->input('product')) //check

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your route's parameter is `{product}` but you're sending the ID as `$subproduct`, and your syntax for generating the route is incorrect.

It should look like this:

```
route('cart.add', ['product' => $subproduct->id])
```

[You can read more on URL generation here.](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/urls#the-basics)

Comment: Thanks for your response Sir. Yet, this would throw me `Undefined Variable:Subproduct` error.

Comment: By the way, `{product}` doesn't appear to be the problem, the problem is that I can't pass the selected id, if I hardcode any id whithin that route I'm able to `dd($product)}` at the controller without problem.